# Proving the required condition for $f(x)$ from given information

Tags: functions, derivatives

> Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable function such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f''(x)-2f'(x)+f(x)\geq  e^x$ then prove that $f’(x)\cdot f(x)$ has at least one root in $(0,1)$.

**My thought**:

$$f''(1)-2f'(1)\geq e$$
and
$$f''(0)-2f'(0)\geq 1$$
If we assume $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and the function $g'(x)$ is $0$ at least once in the domain of $f$ such that $x\in(0,1)$. Also if we use the given equation we get $e>f''(a)-f(a)>1$ for any $a$ in $(0,1)$ where $g'(x)$ may be zero at least once in $(0,1)$.

After this I am not able to think how to proceed further. Please explain in simpler terms as I as newbie in this zone of mathematics. :-)

Comment: Is my editing correct?

Comment: Hint @jayant98: If you put your math inside dollar symbols \$ it will render better.

Comment: Thank you for editing.

Comment: @jayant98 The condition $f''(x)-2f'(x)+f(x)\geq  e^x$ seems to be useless here. Is your statement correct?

Comment: Yes. It has come in the exam. Also @red_trumpet helped me to solve it correctly.

Comment: Actually this question had many tail question for which this information was needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just an application of [Rolle's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle's_theorem). $f(0)=f(1)$, therefore there exist $x\in (0,1)$ with $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: OK I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Would be nice if you accepted my answer ;)

Comment: One more doubt if I want to prove if f(x)<0 for x in (0,1). Then how I will show it?